# b+ tree store on disk for database system

Tags: tree, disk

I need save one B+ tree on disk after the insertions, for remake it in other situation using it index for reference. This situation accured when i needed to use the structure B+ for create index on tables in database system. The main problem is to save it on disk and restore it equal with all the poiters and stuffs. Please help me!